# How to create custom route in magento2

Tags: magento-2.2.5, router, di.xml

**I have used below code in di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customrouter" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Custom\Catalog\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But i am not able to call the funtion Custom\Catalog\Controller\Router also to tried to exit the code but unable to reach given controller. Can any one give me solution

Comment: I want to display error page when some url occurs For that i am using custom route

Comment: @mohammad has given answer try that

Comment: It might help you in details https://tagvibe.com/custom-router-with-a-front-controller-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 7):

Using **"Magento\Framework\App\RouterList"** we use the di.xml file in our module.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="customrouter" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\CustomRouter</item>
                  <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
              </item>
          </argument>
      </arguments>
  </type>
```

After that we need to create a CustomRouter class.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/CustomRouter.php :**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;
class CustomRouter implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
   protected $actionFactory;
   protected $_response;
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
   ) {
       $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
       $this->_response = $response;
   }
   public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
   {
       $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
       if(strpos($identifier, 'customrouter') !== false) {
       $request->setModuleName('customrouter')-> //module name
       setControllerName('index')-> //controller name
       setActionName('index')-> //action name
       setParam('param', 3); //custom parameters
       } else {
           return false;
       }
       return $this->actionFactory->create(
           'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
           ['request' => $request]
       );
   }
}
```

And finally you need to create a routes.xml file.
**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/routes.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
      <route id="customrouter" frontName="customrouter">
          <module name="Vendor_Module" />
      </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing/creating the file at `/etc/frontend/di.xml`

Notice the "**frontend**" in the path

I had this issue and the developer docs didn't make it clear. When I consulted another module, Magento's CMS implementation, I saw this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/frontend/di.xml

Answer (score 0):

> Frontend route

Routes.xml
To register a frontend route, we must create a routes.xml file:

File: app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<!--Use router 'standard' for frontend route-->
<router id="standard">
    <!--Define a custom route with id and frontName-->
    <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
        <!--The module which this route match to-->
        <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

Please look into the code, you will see it’s very simple to register a route. You must use the standard router for the frontend. This route will have a child which define the module for it and 2 attributes:

The id attribute is a unique string which will identify this route. You will use this string to declare the layout handle for the action of this module
The frontName attribute is also a unique string which will be shown on the url request. For example, if you declare a route like this:

> Admin route

This route will be same as the frontend route but you must declare it in adminhtml folder with router id is admin.

File: app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<!--Use router 'admin' for admin route -->
<router id="admin">
    <!--Define a custom route with id and frontName -->
    <route id="mageplaza_helloworld" frontName="mageplaza_helloworld">
        <!--The module which this route match to-->
        <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

The url of the admin page is the same structure with frontend page, but the admin_area name will be added before route_frontName to recognize this is a admin router. For example, the url of admin cms page:

http:// example.com/index.php/admin/mageplaza_helloworld/controller/action

For Reference: [Magento 2 Routing](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-routing.html)

Comment: I want to create route using <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">

Comment: In case, please follow this magento documentation reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html